# How to find correlation of two set of software requirements

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a thought to find correlation between given set of high level software requirements to customer requirement specification both of which are represented by English text. I want to do this to find which high level requirement corresponds to which customer requirement specification. Can anyone guide me how to do this? Are there any open source libraries to use?

I don't know much on machine learning or natural language processing, so have not tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use many methods
One of them I like is using NLTK or spaCy to tokenize and preprocess the text, and then use scikit-learn to compute the similar.

Here is an example:

```
import nltk

def split_sentences(text):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    
    tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    
    sentences = []
    
    buffer = []
    
    for word, tag in tagged_words:
        if tag == 'VBZ' or tag == 'VBP' or tag == 'VBG' or tag == 'VBN' or tag == 'VBD':
            if buffer:
                sentence = ' '.join(buffer)
                sentences.append(sentence)
                buffer = []
        else:
            buffer.append(word)
    
    if buffer:
        sentence = ' '.join(buffer)
        sentences.append(sentence)
    
    return sentences
```